# InstanceState not saving

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out why my bundle SavedInstanceState is not saving when the application closes. Chances are it's just something stupid that I didn't know about though! The main activity doesn't have much in it, just a page adapter for transitioning screens, because that is a major part of what I'm going to try to make. Most of the code right now is in my StandFragment.java,  it's the first page that shows up when you open the app. That's where the save state and that sort of thing is.

MainActivity:
          public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));       
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos){
        switch(pos){
        case 0: return StandFragment.newInstance("STAND");
        case 1: return CartFragment.newInstance("CART");
        case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("THIRD");
        case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("FOURTH");
        case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("FIFTH");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

}

StandFragment:

```
      public class StandFragment extends Fragment{

private int totalMoney;
private int moneyPerSec;
private int moneyPerClick;
Handler handleCounter = new Handler();
TextView counter;
TextView perSecCounter;
Button buttonMoney;
Button buttonMoneyPerSec;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand_frag, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buttonMoney = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.buttonMoney);
    buttonMoneyPerSec = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.buttonMoneyPerSec);
    counter = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    perSecCounter = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMonPerSec);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvStandFrag);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

    handleCounter.post(updateCounter);
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        moneyPerSec = 1;
        moneyPerClick = 1;
        totalMoney=0;
    }
    else{
        moneyPerSec = savedInstanceState.getInt("moneyPerSec");
        moneyPerClick = savedInstanceState.getInt("moneyPerClick");
        totalMoney = savedInstanceState.getInt("totalMoney");
    }

    buttonMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            totalMoney += moneyPerClick;
            counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
            perSecCounter.setText(""+moneyPerSec);
        }
    });
    buttonMoneyPerSec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (totalMoney>=10){
                totalMoney-=10;
                counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
                moneyPerSec++;
                perSecCounter.setText(""+moneyPerSec);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}

Runnable updateCounter = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        totalMoney += moneyPerSec;
        counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
        handleCounter.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putInt("totalMoney",totalMoney);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("moneyPerSec",moneyPerSec);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("moneyPerClick",moneyPerClick);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
public static StandFragment newInstance(String text){

    StandFragment f = new StandFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState()` is not for persistent storage. It is only there to save particular state about that *instance* of the Fragment (e.g. during configuration changes, or if your app is killed in the background and the Fragment should be recreated). If you're closing your app entirely (i.e. finishing the `Activity`) then your state will not be saved, as that instance is no longer needed.

For persistent storage, you could look into either `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Alright, thank you! For some reason I thought save Instance State would transfer variables. One more question though, would it work to save say the state of a button? Like if it was visible or not?

Comment: Yes, but only for that instance of the Fragment (so if you rotate the app, you could keep and save a boolean (the state of the button) and re-apply it in `onViewCreated()`.

Answer (score 1):

onSaveInstanceState() is only called when the Android system may need to recreate that particular instance of the Fragment.

You have to save your data on onSaveInstanceState() of your Activity